# Jquery ui vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, user-interface, scroll

I have be working on a vertical jquery scroll and i am pretty close now but it seems to be scrolling the wrong way and i really haven't got a clue why.

can someone please help here is the link.

http://dropp.users35.interdns.co.uk/scroll/

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you change `ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.height() - scrollContent.height() )` to `ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.height() + scrollContent.height() )` (note changing the minus sign to a plus sign)?

Comment: Got it, but, wait a moment.... why to answer you? YOU HAVE 26 [!] UNACCEPTED ANSWERS. "Wake up Dorothy!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, I tested it on my end it is working fine

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdqm2/)**

```
$(function () {
    var scrollPane = $(".slider_container");
    var scrollContent = $(".scroll-content");

    // Slider

    $('#slider').slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        value: 100,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.value);
            console.log(scrollPane.height());

            if (scrollContent.height() > scrollPane.height()) {
                scrollContent.css("margin-top", (-1 * (scrollPane.height() - ((scrollPane.height() * ui.value) / 100))) + "px");

            } else {
                scrollContent.css("margin-top", 0);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Legend thanks dont know how you got it to work in jsfiddle i was trying for ages aswell so thanks for that

Comment: YOU HAVE 26 [!] UNACCEPTED ANSWERS, how can you expect to get any further help?

Comment: +1 for providing a jsFiddle link since the original example the OP made is down.